# subaru forester 2019 tailgate will not open

Tags: forester, tailgate

tailgate stopped working only beeps 3 times does nothing. remote, internal and button on tailgate all the same 3 beeps does nothing else will not open. Have read manual which has not response to this issue.

Comment: Is there a emergency latch to pop up? Can you try that and see if it opens the gate?

Comment: Is it stil under warranty?